# How can I use FTP to update my website from a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn

I spent some time looking for an efficient way to update my website from a svn repository, but all I can find is to "svn update" directly from the web server, or use a pre/post-commit hook.

Since I don't have ssh access to my web server, I can't really use "svn update", so I tested a pre/post-commit hook (svn2web) which was practical, but not reliable enough. So I look over the internet and found [Springloops](http://www.springloops.com), which is very satisfying because it has a FTP deploy feature that allows me to update my website directly from the svn repository.

Unfortunately, it isn't free, and I like to have full control of my repository. So my question is:

**Is there any tool or script that allows me to update my website over FTP from my Subversion repository ?**

Just like they do at Springloops (or Beanstalk).

Thank you very much for your help, I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/). It's extremely powerful and can do a full checkout, zip it up, and push it to the server over ftp using the new "copy" deployment strategy:

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

See http://www.capify.org/upgrade/whats-new for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, but I think it is necessary to have SSH access on the server to use Capistrano. Is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Ci Factory has support for it - http://cifactory.org/joomla/

Answer (score 0):

What if use post commit hook to do:

1. SVN Update or export on localhost
2. Connect to FTP from localhost
3. Copy all files to FTP